# How to make sweetAlert2 input accept decimal point number type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to save and retrieve a number with sweetAlert and localStorage. I want to use the retrieved value to setState() inside my component.Here is my setup:

```
state={
rateValue=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rate")) 
}


overtimeRate(){
   Swal.fire({
    title: "insert new rate",
    text: "overtime",
    input: 'number',
    showCancelButton: false        
}).then((result) => {
    localStorage.setItem("rate", result.value);
    this.setState({overtimeRate: result.value});
  })
    
}


// then am making use of the state like so
```

```
render(){

return{
<Button onClick={()=>this.overtimeRate()}>Add overtime</Button>
{rateValue * 8}
}
}
```

Whenever i input an interger 1, 2, 3 it works fine, but whenever i try number with decimal point e.g 2.2,1.4 i get an error from sweetAlert. How do I make sweetAlert accept numbers with decimals

Comment: what is the error thrown ?

Comment: I get a (!) Error on sweetAlert box

Comment: keeping input =  "text" and using a validator to check input entered is a number will this work ?

Comment: Your suggestion did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped ☺️.... happy coding